# Get all the emails and the word just before the email starts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, text, nlp

I am trying to parse my dataset to get all the emails and the word just before the email. For example if I have a row like this:

```
sno                                                text
1        From: m.kro@b.org To: Cha.Sh@dys.com Hi my name is Sam and my email is samwise@gmail.com
```

Then I want to capture it as:

```
sno                                                text                                              emails
1        From: m.kro@b.org To: Cha.Sh@dys.com Hi my name is Sam and my email is samwise@gmail.com    [From : m.kro@b.org ,To: Cha.Sh@dys.com, is samwise@gmail.com]
```

My tried solution till now:

I have tried the "find_all" function to get all the emails, but I am having a problem getting the word just before the email starts.

```
df['Full Comments'].str.findall('(\S+@\S+)').str[0]
```

Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pat = '([\w:]+ [\w\.]+@[\w\.]+)'

df['emails'] = df.text.str.extractall(pat).groupby(level=0)[0].agg(list)
```

---

**Update**: you can promote the word to column title with `unstack`:

```
emails = (df.text.str.extractall(pat)
       .reset_index('match', drop=True)
       .set_index([0],append=True)[1]
       .unstack()
    )
```

df = df.join(emails)

Output (without the join part):

```
0       From:             To:                 is 
0  m.kro@b.org  Cha.Sh@dys.com  samwise@gmail.com
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Is there also a way to make columns based on the first word? and in that column the email is there.